# Splitting 1 string with ':' seperator

Tags: c#, split, streamreader

I am trying to make program that changes twitter account's password automaticly with selenium
it works perfectly but my question is lets say I have 10 twitter accounts in .txt file which format is

```
id:password
id:password
id:password
```

first of all. I want to read this txt file with c# and then separate them id(0),password(1) 
how can I do this?

Comment: `id:password` is in continue in one line or each pair is in new line?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Select(x => x.Split(':')).Select(x => new { id = x[0], password = x[1] })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you could split it up.  Go ahead and rework it to fit your specific requirements.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    while (true)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();            

        if (line == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] idPasswords = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < idPasswords.length; i++)
            {
                string[] idPassword = idPasswords[i].split(":");
                string id = idPassword[0];
                string password = idPassword[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I want to pick my txt file from a button. how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As Enigmativity mentioned in comment section you can use `ReadAllLines` method:

```
var users=  File.ReadAllLines("t.txt")
.Select(l=>new {id= l.Split(':')[0] ,password= l.Split(':')[1] })
.ToList();
```